# Why two 'be's in 'be bereaved'?

Tags: etymology

Isn't the infinitive **be** in [**be** bereaved](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bereave) redundant? [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bereave&searchmode=none) looks complex and refers to [bereft](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bereft).

'Origin' on ODO suggests to 'see be-, [reave](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reave)', but doesn't the prefix 'be-' already suffice?

> **reave** = [no object] *archaic* 1. Carry out raids in order to plunder
>   [with object] 1.2. Steal (something).

Comment: The (copulative) verb _be_ has a completely different function than the prefix _-be_, so why would it be redundant? _I am bereaved_ has a completely different meaning than _I am reaved_ or _I bereaved_. In the first case something was stolen from me, in the second case I am the stolen object and in the last case, I was the one doing the stealing!

Comment: @oerkelens Would you like to recast your comment as an answer, for which I’ll happily upvote? Also, would you please enlarge on your explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The [prefix *be-*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be-) has a variety of functions; here, its addition has the function of generating an effect via the action of the verb *reave*. The presence of the separate stative verb *be* converts the past participle *bereaved* into what you might think of as an adjectival form of *bereave*.